# Fetching all the images present in a database and display it in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I'm trying to fetch all the images present in a database and display it in ViewPager

Below is my main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();//here i am fetching an image from gallery
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                image.add(stream.toByteArray());
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(COLUMN_NAME, stream.toByteArray());
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                inflateThumbnails();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        status = true;
        drawableFieldNames = R.drawable.class.getFields();
        horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        find view by id
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Gallery.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists ImagesTable (image blob)");
        thumbnailsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container)

        imageName = getResourceName(drawableFieldNames);
        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addImage_button);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        // init viewpager adapter and attach
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), images);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        inflateThumbnails();
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewPagerAdapter.class

```
 package com.example.android.imagegallery;

        import android.content.res.Resources;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
        import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
        import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    // This instance is to hold image resources which are present in drawable folder.
    // In drawable_images I'm fetching all the images from the drawable folder.  
    // images is holding the all the drawable resources value
    private List<Integer> drawable_images;

    private ArrayList<byte[]> db_images = new ArrayList<>();/this instance is to hold images which are present in database

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Integer> imagesList) {
        super(fm);
        this.drawable_images = imagesList;
    }
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<byte[]> image) {
        super(fm);
        this.db_images=image;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    /*byte[] image = this.image.get(position);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        options.inDither = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, options);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        d.getClass().getResource(d.toString());
        return PageFragment.getInstance();*/
        return PageFragment.getInstance(drawable_images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return drawable_images.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't specified your question clearly. What help do you want ? Are there any errors you are unable to resolve ? Or is there anything you are unable to implement ?

Comment: Actually i want to add images from galley and save them in a database and display them in viewpager, so can you please tell me how to implement this @Varun Kumar

Comment: Why do you want to save the images in the database when they are already present on your device ?

Comment: if i want to add images from gallery in an app how should i approach it?

Comment: Gallery shows all the images present on the device. By help of File handing you can access all the images on the device, retrieve them and show them in your app.

Comment: Actually I don't want to show all the pictures in my gallery, I just want to select an image from my gallery and display it in my app, when I click on a button in the tollbar of my app. Thank you for responding and helping me out.